# Can a class implementing an Interface return is own type

Tags: c#

I'm using .NET CORE 7 Preview and I created a very basic interface :

```
public interface IRegularPolygon
{
    static readonly int SideCount;

    public RectangleF Bounds { get; }

    public IList<PointF> Points { get; }

    public static abstract IRegularPolygon Create(Point location, int radius);

    public static abstract Point GetCentroid(PointF[] points);
}
```

Which I implement in a couple a classes. E.G :

```
class Hexagon : IRegularPolygon
{
    // Working
    public static IRegularPolygon Create(Point location, int radius)
    {
    // Creating the Hexagon
    }

   // Working too, but I would like to avoid casting
   public static IRegularPolygon Create(Point location, int radius)
   {
       // Creating the Hexagon
       return (Hexagon)hexagon;  // still need to cast (Hexagon) when calling this method
   }

   // What I want to achieve.
   // [ERROR] Don't implement IRegularPolygon
   public static Hexagon Create(Point location, int radius)
   {
     // Creating the Hexagon;
     return hexagon // as Hexagon type
   }
}
```

So, it's working. I can use `var hexagon = (Hexagon)Hexgon.Create();`

I do understand the compilation error in the method `public static Hexagon Create(Point location, int radius)`.

I was hoping that since I implement the interface, I could return the type itself (`Hexagon` in that example).

Is this even possible to achieve ? Or should I rather go for a inheritance ?

Thanks for your answers !

Aurélien.

Comment: One option: make the interface generic with a recursive type parameter: `interface IRegularPolygon<T> where T : IRegularPolygon<T> {...}`, then declare `static abstract T Create();` and provide `class Hexagon : IRegularPolygon<Hexagon> {static Hexagon Create(){...}}` as the implementation.

Comment: ... but then you are doomed ... if `A : IRegularPolygon<A>` and `B  : IRegularPolygon<B>` then `A` and `B` do not have common interface

Comment: @Selvin Correct, you'd need to keep all the other members in the non-generic version and then extend that with the generic interface for it to work (and `Create` would not be shared across implementations)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you define an interface is so the caller can know what to expect. To the caller it shouldn't matter what implementation of IRegularPolygon you return. You can return Hexagon if you cast it to IRegularPolygon.

However if you're simply looking to enforce a pattern where every class has a Create method, then an interface is not what you need. Maybe an abstract base class will serve you better:

```cs
public abstract class RegularPolygon
{
    public static RegularPolygon Create(Point location, int radius) 
    {
        throw new NotImplementedExecption();
    }
}

public class Hexagon : RegularPolygon
{
    public static new Hexagon Create(Point location, int radius)
    {
        //implement method
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is also what I was thinking. I was asking the question because I was not not sure it could be doable. Still, desing-wise, is it better than I go for the interface and cast ?

Comment: I made a small adjustment to the abstract class: a static method always needs to define a body.

Comment: Indeed. But in your humble opinion, wouldn't it be better to stick to an interface ?

Comment: What's best depends on what you're trying to achieve. An interface suggests all implementations of IRegularPolygon are exchangeable to the caller, which supposedly isn't how it should work. If you want a simple shortcut to creating a new instance of a specific polygon type, then either a constructor or simply having `static Create()` as a manual pattern would already do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out ! I opted for moving the Create() method in the constuctor. Easier and cleaner !